# while creating a thread , the parameter which we pass in the constructor contains (this) why it is used?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to programming. While creating a thread, why do we pass (this) as a parameter?

```java
private Thread filePuller = null;

filePuller = new Thread(this, "FilePuller");
```

Comment: We'd need to see the code.  Off hand it looks like an anti-pattern.

Comment: `this` refers to the object you're currently in, and if I had to guess it implements the `Runnable` interface, which is the first parameter to `Thread`

Comment: @markspace Why an anti pattern ?  Implementing `Runnable` is generally good and often a better alternative than extending `Thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you are explicitly instantiating the `Thread` class and passing the current class's instance to the new thread. For details, see [this Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.String-) for details on that constructor. Your current object is an instance of the [`Runnable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) (you should be able to check that by checking out the code where the class starts). So, later in your code, when `filePuller.start()` is likely called, it will call the current class's `run()` method. You should be able to see the implementation of the `run()` method somewhere in your current class - either in the same file or in the code of a superclass. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the interface that your class implements.
It should be Runnable.
So you pass this (that refers to object of your class) to Thread as a "task" to execute.
Your class overrides method

```
public  void run(){
...
}
```

that will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

That is a design choice.
The `Thread` class comes with many overloaded constructors. 
Here you use this one :

> `public Thread(Runnable target, String name)`
>
> Allocates a new Thread object. This constructor has the same effect as
>   Thread (null, target, name).
>
> Params:
>
> `target` – the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is
>   started. If null, this thread's run method is invoked.
>
> `name` – the name of the new thread

So the `this` in your code refers to a `Runnable` instance which the `run()` method is invoked when the thread starts.

This code makes sense if the class implements `Runnable` and don't want extend `Thread` for any good reason  such as the class extends already another class or we don't want to leak the `Thread` implementation in the class definition.